# Can Google analytics be hosted on a different URL embedded in an Iframe

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I have a website `www.site.com` that contains a iframe which embeds another site `www.another.com` which contains google analytics code. Now if a user navigated to my website at `www.site.com` will the google analytics code in the iframe for `www.another.com` track that user? If not is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is extensive documentation about this [over here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite).